# VS 2013 Intellisense for Interpolated Strings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I recently upgraded to a new version of MvvmCross for my Android App.  I am still running VS 2013.  I installed the Microsoft.net.compilers nuget package and the code compiles fine.  The problem is that the Intellisense still shows the following line as an error:

```
changed.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => { var test = $"{e.Action}{e.NewItems}{e.NewStartingIndex}{e.OldItems}{e.OldStartingIndex}"; };
```

Is a way to add this to the Visual Studio 2013 Intellisense?

Comment: Intellisense changed a *lot* in 2015 to take advantage of Roslyn. 2013 has no knowledge of Roslyn or interpolated strings. Why don't you upgrade to 2015? Community Edition is free.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos VS 2015 would require Windows 10.  This is our very busy season and my boss doesn't want platform changes with possible unfavorable results right now.  I will do that in the fall.

Comment: No it wouldn't! There's no such requirement and in fact it's the first time I hear of such a thing! It runs perfectly well on Windows 7. If it didn't, it would be impossible to test and release VS 2015 before Windows 10 came out, wouldn't it??????? As for unfavorable results - you *are* trying to use C# 6 features in VS 2013 aren't you? Anyway, you can install both editions on the same machine

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am using MvvmCross in my project and it contains an interpolated string in one of the required classes.  That is the only reason I care about C# 6.  That being said, I though the whole reason for VS 2015 was Windows 10.  I just assumed you had to have it in order to run it.  You had to have Windows 8 in order to effectively use VS 2013.  I just assumed it was the same for VS 2015.  I will still probably wait until after our busy season, just in case.

Comment: You don't need Windows 8 for Visual Studio 2013. You need it only if you want to create mobile or Store. There are a *lot* of compiler, language and feature improvements in 2015 that have nothing to do with mobile or Store apps.

Comment: I am creating mobile apps.  Do you know if Windows 10 or VS 2015 will affect apps written for Windows RT 8.1?

Comment: Check the site. A hint: I'm installing VS 2015 Update 3 and I just unchecked the 8.1 tools